# Does between in HQL compare strictly or not?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

if I write in HQL

```
A between 5 and 10
```

is that equivalent to

```
A >= 5 and A <= 10
```

or

```
A > 5 and A < 10
```

or some other of the 4 combinations?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I didn't find any specification of the behavior in the Hibernate docs, but the `between` operator in HQL is translated to the `between` operator in SQL, which is inclusive.

So `between` in HQL is also inclusive, that is

```
A between 5 and 10
```

is equivalent to

```
A >= 5 and A <= 10
```

Comment: Here's the specification on JPQL between: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_between

Comment: Notice: Using AWS Glue 1 & 2, `between` is exclusive. It becomes inclusive from Glue 3.

Answer (score 5):

obviously there is some confusion regarding this. natural language would suggest it is exclusive, but this is not true. in reality its A >= 5 and A<=10.
since there were already contradicting answers given (and delted), there needs to be more clarification: (from http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php)

```
Example #1 - Numbers

The following is an SQL statement that uses the BETWEEN function:

SELECT *
FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_id between 5000 AND 5010;

This would return all rows where the supplier_id is between 5000 and 5010, inclusive. It is equivalent to the following SQL statement:

SELECT *
FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_id >= 5000
AND supplier_id <= 5010;
```